# Vue js loop for

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add an a action to my data, this's code=

```
this.array = res.data.data;
        for( i in this.array){
            this.$set(this.array[i], 'action', 
            "<a href='/users/ope/array[i].id'> <v-icon> mdi-account-details-outline </v-icon> </a>"
            ); 
        }
```

but I'm having this error=

```
ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to define the `i` variable using `let` or `const` :

```
for(let i in this.array){
      ...
```

the `i` represents the index, if you want to loop through the values you could use `for(let val of this.array){`